# How to serve MEDIA uploads from summernote in prod hosting?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Good afternoon and Happy New Year!

In the admin panel, when creating a post, the uploaded images are not displayed.
Neither in the admin area nor in the published post.
They are in the folder with the downloaded images, and through the Django admin panel, a link is visible (but it does not open, "Not Found The requested resource was not found on this server") and they are uploaded to the hosting (they appear in the django-summernote folder by dates).
Tell me how to fix the situation?

The statics loaded normally, everything is displayed OK.
The only problem is with those files that the user uploads when the post is compiled.

.htaccess at the slightest change from the standard one provided by the hoster - the site stops opening. From this and the working statics, I assume that Apache is configured normally, especially since the hoster's infrastructure does not contain a mention or a requirement to change it.
Thanks!

The settings.py settings are below:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
SUMMERNOTE_THEME = 'bs4'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'blog/media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/%Y-%m-%d", blank=True, null=True)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/api/article/%i/" % self.id

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

There is a suspicion that the problem is in this 404 error, but how to solve it I xs.

Thanks!

.htaccess

```
PassengerAppRoot "/home/app/mynewapp" 
PassengerBaseURI "/" 
PassengerPython "/home/app/virtualenv/mynewapp/3.9/bin/python" 
<IfModule Litespeed> 
</IfModule>
```

**UPD!**
I'm dont know why my hosting doesn't work without `.htaccess` and in the same time in answer i'm see nginx like server....
[Answer from server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLnkz.jpg)

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYtdT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but I managed to fix it by removing the `upload to`argument in the media field. This ensures medias are uploaded directly to the location specified in the `MEDIA_ROOT`  without creating any additional folder.

Comment: i'm tryed change this - but it's still not working right. Uploaded images saves to MEDIA_ROOT folder - but not showing in post...((((

Comment: If the images are uploaded correctly and you are unable to see them In your post, it could mean your url is not configured properly.